# Syncing Data between MS SQL Server and Oracle Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, coldfusion

My colleague and I are trying to find the best query to sync up an Oracle database with that of a SQL server.  There are about 80k+ rows with ~19 columns of data in each row. We have a linked server setup between the two servers and we have a query that works but for 80k records, the query took 10 hours to copy the records over.  I can post the query we used but I would like to have a fresh set of eyes.  This is a new process so we aren't trying to retrofit a solution to existing code.  LIke I said before, permissions aren't an issue, it is just a matter of getting the data from Point A to Point B in the quickest time.  This is to be used on a coldfusion supported web site and the client would like to click a buttton to sync up the data but again, this is just "wish list" of requirements we are working with.

Additional Thoughs I'd like to add:
We have tried openquery and using linked server but both took about the same time to complete. 
Most are varchar(64 bytes), a couple of varchar(128) and a couple of varchar(12 bytes). 
One suggestion someone else made was to write the data to a flat file, ftp the flat file to Point B and then import it.  That is a viable solution but the more steps we include, the more chances there are of something breaking.

Thanks in advance.  I look forward to seeing y'alls solutions.

Comment: We hadn't thought about it but we _might_ be able to make this a scheduled job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had more success with an SSIS package than linked servers.  If you use the Oracle DLL's, it's not too bad.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on SSIS or Oracle DLL's?  Is this software that would have to be installed?  It _might_ be an option but we would have to check.

Comment: SSIS is what replaced DTS.  SSIS is Microsofts ETL tooling for SQL Server. It comes as part of the SQL Server install. If it wasn't installed when SQL Server was initially installed, here's how to add it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913967

Comment: The Oracle DLLs are those which can be installed from the Oracle Universal Installer (when you install the Oracle Client).  See: http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/InstallODP.htm  The perform better than OLE or MS's Data Provider for Oracle.

Comment: If you're nuking the MS data and replacing it with Oracle data, you can TRUNCATE the Table and do a BULK INSERT - but BULK INSERT from SSIS is ugly (IMHO).   I move more than 80k rows twice a day with similar amount of column

Comment: @dan_Andrews since you do somehting similar, are you kicking this off from a web page or do you have a scheduled job running this?  Running this process from a scheduled job might be an option for us, too.

Comment: @dan-Andrews since you do somehting similar, are you kicking this off from a web page or do you have a scheduled job running this? Running this process from a scheduled job might be an option for us, too.

Comment: @Rob-Brooks-Bilson thanks for the link to install it.  Thankfully our server already has it installed so that is one item we can mark off this extremely long list. :D

Comment: @Dan-andrews looks like we are going to use the SSIS route.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad it works for you.  Let me know if I can help - for the fun of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Oracle Transparent Gateway](http://oracle-apps-dba.blogspot.com/2008/04/oracle-transparent-gateway-for-ms-sql_16.html)? Here is the [reference manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10544_01/toc.htm). It drives SQL Server from Oracle instead of the other way around.

Comment: No, not yet.  Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Zidsoft [CompareData](http://www.zidsoft.com) you can set up the sync task visually and also scheduling it to run via the commandline. Disclosure: I am the developer of this product.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the product, [be sure to disclose it within your answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)