# solution to deploy data in SQL from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view

our customer (university) have Oracle 10 database server all student data stored in this data base.
we installed ID badge software which using SQL database, i don't need to re enter all student data to the ID badge software i need to use the existing data in Oracle.

is there any solution to deploy data in SQL from Oracle ?

thanks

Comment: By "SQL", do you mean SQL Server rather than [structured query language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)? You should tag the question appropriately to get the right people looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313198(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: but if any update happen in ORACLE DB it will reflect in SQL ?

Comment: @Bayan, this is for one time migration, later to sync up these you can use SQL server integration services or third party sync software

Comment: do you have any name of third party software to make this sync?

Comment: There is a discussion on sync at this post and also some software which does the sync http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720271/syncing-data-between-ms-sql-server-and-oracle-server